# Are there any well-known Internal DSL Proof Assistants?

Tags: history, software-request

Proof assistants like [Coq](https://coq.inria.fr/) have their own extensible syntax that's rather different from a general purpose language.

I'm curious whether there are any well-known proof assistants that are implemented as libraries in a general-purpose programming language such as Haskell or OCaml.

For example, using pseudocode.

```
proofEnvironment := NewProofEnvironment()
proofEnvironment.SetGoal("forall x . x = x")
proofEnvironment.ApplyTactic(...)
// Exports a proof of the targeted goal in some manner.
// For example as a metamath proof or another similar minimal format.
proofEnvironment.Export(...)
```

Comment: Perhaps something like [HOL Light](https://github.com/jrh13/hol-light)? Or, more broadly, any prover following the LCF philosophy with an extensible metalanguage implementation?

Comment: To the user that voted to close this so far, why does this "need more focus"? It seems two users were already able to give fairly well-received answers. I'm voting to "leave open" until I'm convinced otherwise :)

Comment: I updated the preamble to remove the bit about prover9, which is extraneous. Now it just talks about Coq, which isn't an internal DSL.

Comment: What about python bindings to an SMT solver? Would that count?

Comment: Also, what about LiquidHaskell, would that count?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As [Alex Nelson](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/users/14/alex-nelson) [pointed out](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/11), I think this is exactly the [LCF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_for_Computable_Functions) approach to theorem proving.  See [The LCF Approach
to Theorem Proving](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Ejrh13/slides/manchester-12sep01/slides.pdf) for details.

[HOL-Light](https://github.com/jrh13/hol-light) would certainly fit this description.  You literally use HOL-Light inside OCaml.  (Back when I coded in HOL-Light, I would code up my proof in an editor and paste it into an OCaml interpreter.)  You can get a flavor by looking at the HOL Light code.  For example, here is a theorem in HOL Light:

```
let ARITHMETIC_PROGRESSION_LEMMA = prove
 (`!n. nsum(0..n) (\i. a + d * i) = ((n + 1) * (2 * a + n * d)) DIV 2`,
  INDUCT_TAC THEN ASM_REWRITE_TAC[NSUM_CLAUSES_NUMSEG] THEN ARITH_TAC);;
```

Here `prove` takes two arguments, the goal to prove, and a tactic to prove that statement (which is usually a number of tactics changed together with the `THEN` tactical), and it outputs a theorem.  Tactics are just OCaml functions of type `goal -> goalstate`.  (There is also some tooling in HOL-Light to make it more interactive, but that also is just an OCaml DSL used inside the OCaml REPL.)

If I am not mistaken, the [ML family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ML_(programming_language)) of languages were originally designed exactly to be the **M**eta **L**anguage for LCF provers to implement tactics.  From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=ML_(programming_language)&oldid=1065803580#Overview):

> Historically, ML was conceived to develop proof tactics in the LCF theorem prover (whose language, *pplambda*, a combination of the first-order predicate calculus and the simply-typed polymorphic lambda calculus, had ML as its metalanguage).

Comment: Perhaps as an example, older Isabelle theory files were named using `.ml` extension--they were actually ML code.

Answer (score 14):

If you are asking about a kind of embedding advanced proving facilities into modern System F$_\omega$-wannabe languages then I would suggest you to take a look onto Proving Ground base library for Scala by Siddhartha Gadgil:

https://github.com/siddhartha-gadgil/ProvingGround

You can read [original presentaion](https://www.icts.res.in/outreach/kaapi-with-kuriosity/2020may?fbclid=IwAR0wtwZlbuf5_mgZryiY-zhKnTO88hgZpxA_wEh73DBhjeEklhmbrFSbgvQ) by Siddhartha  or take a [Course on Stepik](https://stepik.org/course/2294/promo) by [Dmytro Mitin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5249621/dmytro-mitin?tab=profile).

Here is short example:

```
Theorem proving
import provingground.
import HoTT.
import TLImplicits.
import shapeless.

val indN assoc = 
    NatInd.induc(n :-> (m ∼>: (k ∼>: (add(add(n)(m))(k)
    =:= add(n)(add(m)(k))))))

val hyp = "(n+m)+k=n+(m+k)" :: m ∼>: k ∼>: (add(add(n)(m))(k) 
          =:= add(n)(add(m)(k)))

val assoc = indN assoc(m :∼> (k :∼> add(m)(k).refl))
    (n :∼> (hyp :-> (m :∼> (k :∼> 
         IdentityTyp.extnslty(succ)(add(add(n)(m))(k))
          (add(n)(add(m)(k))) (hyp(m)(k))))))

 assoc !: n ∼>: m ∼>: k ∼>: (add(add(n)(m))(k) =:= add(n)(add(m)(k)))
```

But [beware](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/2983990.2984004) Scala type systems and deal with them accurately, here is fine as we have HOL-like string internalization.

Answer (score 11):

I can't speak to how well-known it is, but [holpy](https://github.com/bzhan/holpy)<sup>[1]</sup> is a fairly recent library that implements higher order logic in Python. The main selling points they describe in the arXiv paper are a "point and click" user interface, a JSON-like format implementing theories, and numerous macros that can be applied for "producing, checking, and storing proofs".

**References:**

1. Bouhua Zhan, [HolPy: Interactive Theorem Proving in Python](https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.05970).
   (accessed February 8, 2022)

Answer (score 5):

This is indeed the LCF approach, and is how the various HOL systems operate to this day. Typically, the systems *do* augment or fiddle with their underlying programming language implementations.  For example, HOL Light fiddles with OCaml's lexical syntax to make the language look more like Classic (*i.e.*, pre-SML) ML. HOL4 extends Poly/ML at the lexing level to support pretty multi-line quotation-syntax (SML string literals can only extend over multiple source-level lines through the use of trailing backslash characters) and some other tricks.